# Python 2 type comments - how can I designate that a return type is a type or a subtype of a particular class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-hinting

So:

```
class A(object): pass

class B(A): pass

def class_factory(letter):
    """rtype : type[A]""" # is this correct ?
    if letter == 'A': return A # note no parenthesis ! returns the type, not an instance
    elif letter == 'B': return B
    raise NotImplementedError
```

Can't seem to find any docs and searching is rather tricky.

Bonus: How would this be achieved in the python 3.5 implementation of type hints ?

Comment: Tried `issubclass(B,A)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "designate"?  Every object knows which class it belongs to.

Comment: Not an answer, but it sounds like this task is something you could be handling in `A.__new__()` instead.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage would be `"""rtype: type"""`.  You are specifying the type of the object that is returned, and no matter whether you are returning A or B, the actual object you return is an instance of `type`.  You can see this if you run the following:

```
class A(object): pass
class B(A): pass
print(type(A))
print(type(A()))
print(type(B))
print(type(B()))
```

Because you are returning a `type` in every case, the return type should be `type`.  There is no way of specifying that the `class` object you return has specific properties, since those properties aren't dependent on the type of the object you return, but on the specific *instance* of the type you return.

Comment: Yes thanks - so there are no generics for this case ?

Comment: Correct, because both things you're returning have the same type (they're both classes).  It would be like returning two `Cat` objects, one cat named Scruffy and one named Fluffy: they're both instances of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Type hinting in doc strings is not standardised. So there a number of answers.

That being said I would say your return type is a function that returns instances of A. That is, a class is a callable that return instances of itself. Which would be something like:

```
(Foo, Bar) -> A
```

Where the `Foo` and `Bar` are the types of the arguments to the function.

Comment: Hmm interesting - you mean the types of the arguments in the `A.__init__()` ?

Answer (score -1):

not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve here but something like this can help ..

```
>>> class A(object):
    pass

>>> class B(A):
    pass

>>> def test(letter):
    if isinstance(letter,A):
       Do something if letter is of object A
    elif isinstance(letter,B):
       Do something if letter is of object B
```